# When clicking on the tabs why not toggle on every click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When clicking on the tabs, the accordion is hiding and showing but not on every click. See [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6sjruyya/1/).

```
<div role="tabpanel" id="tabs-test">
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#divTab1" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#divTab2" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#divTab3" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#divTab4" aria-controls="" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content-outer">
                  <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="divTab1">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="divTab2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="divTab3">The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="divTab4">The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /tabpanel -->
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to simulate an accordion?  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: @Jonathan - I am using the bootstrap tabs mark-up to simulate an accordion if viewed at the smaller screen size. So need to use the tabs mark-up (not the other way around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move you `$(this).click(function() {` outside of the `$(".nav-tabs > li").click(function() {`, and instead use the jQuery `.on` function for the "active" li, I think you will get the desired results:

```
// Update: Use a differenet onclick for the active and the
// non-active, and force a .show()
$(".nav-tabs").on('click','li:not(.active)',function() {
    $(NewContent).appendTo($(this));
    $(NewContent).show();
});
$(".nav-tabs").on('click','li.active',function() {
    $(NewContent).toggle();
});
```

Have a look at the updated, functional Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5875/

**Why your code isn't working:**

Essentially, the way you were doing it, you are adding a `.click` event every time that you click an `li`.  When you have added the click code an odd number of times your code works as expected, but when you have an even number, it will toggle on/off, giving the illusion that nothing happened.

Check this fiddle and open your console to better understand the principle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5864/

Comment: You are right '$(this).click(function() {' is not needed. What you have done is correct although I don't think we can use .toggle as clicking through the tabs it is still not showing the content.

Comment: Also, if you don't mind...how would you hide the first tab by default?

Comment: Awesome!  To hide the first by default: `$(NewContent).appendTo(".nav-tabs li.active").hide();`  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5877/

Comment: Thank you so much @jonathan! Have learned something from this too!

Comment: FYI. hide(); seems to collapsing the tab content section when scrolling on a mobile phone. Any workaround for this?